Disable auto focus on select2 drop-down in modal?
I have added multiple Select2 dropdowns in my modal and initialized these select dropdowns when the modal opens. There was one problem: when we open the Select2 dropdown, its positioning was not correct. To fix this, I added a method.select2('open').select2('close'); to open and close the Select2 dropdown when the modal is opened. Now the positioning is correct, but there is another issue: when the Select2 dropdown opens and closes, all Select2 elements are focused, which activates the select and scrolls the page.
<a
  class="edu_btn edu_btn_primary me-10"
  data-toggle="modal"
  data-target="#dataFilter"
  ><i class="fa fa-filter me-1" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Filter</span></a
>
<div
  class="modal center-modal sk_modal fade"
  id="dataFilter"
  tabindex="-1"
  aria-labelledby="dataFilterLabel"
  aria-hidden="true"
>
  <div class="modal-dialog w-400">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title modal-t-color">
          <i class="fa fa-filter pe-2" aria-hidden="true"></i> Filter
        </h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <select data-placeholder="Select Library" class="customSelect">
                <option>option1</option>
                <option>option2</option>
              </select>
              <select data-placeholder="Select Library" class="customSelect">
                <option>option1</option>
                <option>option2</option>
              </select>
              <select data-placeholder="Select Library" class="customSelect">
                <option>option1</option>
                <option>option2</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('.customSelect')
      .each(function () {
        var dropdownParents = $(this).parents('.modal');
        $(this).select2({
          dropdownParent: dropdownParents,
        });
      })
      .select2('open')
      .select2('close');
  });
});

I want to disable Select2 focus when the modal is opened.

Your question is not very clear. Can you please reproduce this in https://jsfiddle.net/ and post the link here for better understanding ?

@AnoopLL Here is jsfiddle url you can check it
https://jsfiddle.net/sachinThakurEdunext/vfqgm8nu/2/

Its been caused by the select2('open').select2('close');. If you see the Autofocus comes at the last option because the close closed the last drop down hence its getting Autofocused. I removed select2('open').select2('close'); from jsfiddle code and is working intact
